# ASP.net MVC listbox get all values in post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, listbox, listboxitem

May I know what is the best approach of posting all contents in listbox via asp.net mvc? Here is my a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

So whenever I submit or save. These values will be posted without selecting value.

Can this be done  in html helper or jquery? And what is the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the options in jQuery before you post the values. After that you can assign those values to an array, and post it with ajax. In your controller you should take an integer array as a parameter.

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692310/14124884)